# FS for cross platform developement

Tags: node.js, browser, electron, cross-platform, fs

I know `fs` (file system) is not supported on browser mode for security purposes. But is there any way / module available that abstracts this and somehow allows for browser use?

Asking because I am working on a cross-platform app that should support Electron (where fs is allowed) and web (browser). I am hoping there is a way to 'quickly' switch between Electron and web without having to maintain multiple code base.

Help please! I've been searching the web for a couple of days now and can't seem to find anything useful :(